# Should AppDelegate be used for sharing data?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Should I use AppDelegate for sharing data?

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

My friend said using AppDelegate for this is bad because it uses more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't use more memory : you need N bytes to store your data, whatever the place. But it's a bad practice from a programmer's perspective, as it breaks the MVC principles of separation and self-containment.

You should provide more information about what kind of data you need to share and store.

Comment: i'm use @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *data; and 
    data = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];   and    AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [appdelegate.data setString:STD]; something like that

Comment: What's its use? There has to be some better place to put it, depending on how you need to pass this object around between controllers.